# Using a function to pass a parameter for ng-show

Tags: angularjs

I have a menu and I want to hide certain li's in the menu based on the logged in user's read write Access.

Here is the html:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="adminLink">Admin</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/config">Configuration</a></li>
            <li ng-show="showPage('CRM Read')"><a id="crmLink" href="#/crm">CRM</a></li>
            <li><a id="rbacLink" href="#/rbac">RBAC</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li style="position: absolute; left: 90%;"><a href="#/security/logout" >Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

And here are the functions:

```
 $scope.showIfAuthorized = function(checkRole) {
        var checkRole = checkRole;
        var checkingRole = AuthService.hasRole(checkRole);

        return checkingRole;
    }
    $scope.showPage = $scope.showIfAuthorized(checkRole);

authService.hasRole = function(role) {
        console.log('authService: begin role=' + role);
        console.log('Session.roles' + Session.roles);
        if (Session.roles != null) {
            document.cookie = "Session.roles="+Session.roles;
        }

        if (Session.roles == null) {
            Session.roles = authService.getCookie("Session.roles");
            console.log("Session.roles after refresh = " + Session.roles);
        }
        if (Session.roles === null && authService.getCookie("Session.roles") === null)
            return false;

        var indx = Session.roles.indexOf(role);
        console.log('hasRole: indx = ' + indx);
        if (indx >= 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

When I try running this I get the error, "checkRole is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not execute showIfAuthorized function directly. The code should be like

```
$scope.showPage = $scope.showIfAuthorized;
```

Or You can directly call showIfAuthorized function from ng-show like

```
ng-show = "showIfAuthorized('CRM Read')"
```

Comment: $scope.showPage = $scope.showIfAuthorized how can we accept checkRole parameter?

Comment: I am passing just a function pointer of showIfAuthorized to showPage and this function is being called from ng-show in html so it will get checkRole parameter from there.So actually it will execute showIfAuthorized function only.

Answer (score 0):

Change code to

```
$scope.showPage = function(checkRole){
  //indirectly calling method
  $scope.showIfAuthorized(checkRole);
}
```

Otherwise directly called method from UI

```
ng-click = "showIfAuthorized('CRM Read')"
```

Hope this is helpful to you.